# Is this combined scoring rule code-golf, popularity-contest, or code-challenge?

Tags: discussion, tags, winning-criteria

[This question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20531/6788) has an interesting scoring rule.

> calculate the score by dividing number of bytes by number of votes - lowest score wins.

One could argue that [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) *both* apply. One could also argue that they are mutually exclusive, and that [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) is appropriate.

For posterity's sake, what's the consensus here?

Comment: In my opinion, [tag:code-golf] should only be for pure code-golf. In this case, I tagged it as [tag:code-challenge], removed [tag:code-golf], and kept [tag:popularity-contest] as the scoring is heavily based on votes.

Comment: I don't know which tag to apply, but it seems to be the worst of both worlds.

Comment: Related: [This question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20545/string-of-alphanumeric-characters-to-a-sorted-list-of-comma-separated-ranges) is missing a winning criteria. Should it be marked [tag:code-golf] or [tag:code-challenge]? It seems very close to a [tag:code-golf], so maybe that is appropriate. On the other hand, it is not strict [tag:code-golf] scoring because it has a free giveaway (note: if I interpreted the question right, the Bonus is not related to score; it is reputation)

Comment: @Quincunx I'd say that's still [code-golf] because it's only the hardcoded input that's being ignored for scoring purposes, and that's the same for everyone regardless of language used.